# Configuration key 'authorizationUrl' is set to null but expected STRING]

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6, securesocial

I am using securesocial master snapshot version in play framwork 2.6. The error says 'authorizationUrl' is expecting string, that is what I did. Please help if I am making any mistake.
Below is my securesocial.conf file

```
  securesocial {

  applicationHost=localhost
  applicationPort=9000

  onLoginGoTo = /home

  onLogoutGoTo = /login

  ssl = false

  sessionTimeOut = 60

  github {
    authorizationUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize"
    accessTokenUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"
    clientId = 30032e485b22d8fb97f7
    clientSecret = 1b0d88c23ff56612970ac446e972035ccafbbc3e
  }

  userpass {
    withUserNameSupport = false
    sendWelcomeEmail = true
    enableGravatarSupport = true
    signupSkipLogin = true
    tokenDuration = 60
    tokenDeleteInterval = 5
    minimumPasswordLength = 8
    enableTokenJob = true
    hasher = bcrypt
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was found deeper down in the error. The error message points to a jar file in the cache (`.ivy2/cache/ws.securesocial/securesocial_2.12/jars/securesocial_2.12-master-SNAPSHOT.jar`).

I this file is unzipped, the `reference.conf` file becomes visible, and the authorizationUrl, etc. for `oauth1Settings` and `oauth2Settings` are set to `null`. Changing these to strings did the trick, but this seems like a very odd fix to have to make.

The final section of the conf file looks like the code below, where the string values were originally null values.

```
oauth1Settings {
    requestTokenUrl = null
    accessTokenUrl = ""
    authorizationUrl = ""
    consumerKey = null
    consumerSecret = null
}

# default settings for oauth2 providers
oauth2Settings {
    # these must always be provided for each provider
    authorizationUrl = ""
    accessTokenUrl = ""
    clientId = ""
    clientSecret = ""

    # optional
    scope = null

    # optional params maps
    authorizationUrlParams {}
    accessTokenUrlParams {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it within your `reference.conf` file and not the `securesocial.conf` file; as you stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to securesocial.conf file. In the  file I have included only github provider while the reference.conf file requires all the providers to be added. Refer this [link](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/conf/securesocial.conf)